# Identify the nearest feature from a GeoJSON file to a given point?

Tags: python, geojson

I am trying to identify the feature nearest to a given point. The features are lines modeling roads in GeoJSON.

Example GeoJSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30356, 29.85715 ], [ -95.30337, 29.85704 ], [ -95.30312, 29.85686 ], [ -95.30281, 29.8566 ], [ -95.30262, 29.85634 ], [ -95.3025, 29.85606 ], [ -95.30247, 29.85576 ], [ -95.30246, 29.85535 ], [ -95.30242, 29.85506 ], [ -95.30233, 29.85486 ], [ -95.30217, 29.85469 ], [ -95.30193, 29.85455 ], [ -95.30167, 29.85452 ], [ -95.30051, 29.85453 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30356, 29.85715 ], [ -95.30336, 29.85723 ], [ -95.3028, 29.85745 ], [ -95.30235, 29.85756 ], [ -95.30192, 29.85762 ], [ -95.30148, 29.85763 ], [ -95.3005, 29.85764 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30051, 29.85453 ], [ -95.3005, 29.85764 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.3005, 29.85764 ], [ -95.29947, 29.85764 ], [ -95.29895, 29.85767 ], [ -95.29844, 29.85776 ], [ -95.29796, 29.85791 ], [ -95.29758, 29.85807 ], [ -95.29659, 29.85858 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30051, 29.85453 ], [ -95.30018, 29.85453 ], [ -95.29984, 29.85458 ], [ -95.29954, 29.85468 ], [ -95.29916, 29.85487 ], [ -95.29894, 29.85495 ], [ -95.29863, 29.85504 ], [ -95.29815, 29.8551 ], [ -95.29767, 29.85509 ], [ -95.29718, 29.85502 ], [ -95.29707, 29.8553 ], [ -95.29693, 29.85547 ], [ -95.29672, 29.85561 ], [ -95.29513, 29.85642 ], [ -95.29561, 29.85713 ], [ -95.2961, 29.85784 ], [ -95.29659, 29.85858 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30609, 29.85973 ], [ -95.30586, 29.8595 ], [ -95.30569, 29.85928 ], [ -95.30553, 29.85904 ], [ -95.3054, 29.85877 ], [ -95.30517, 29.85837 ], [ -95.30493, 29.85813 ], [ -95.30468, 29.85792 ], [ -95.30433, 29.85769 ], [ -95.30356, 29.85715 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.3005, 29.85764 ], [ -95.30053, 29.86077 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30609, 29.85973 ], [ -95.30589, 29.85996 ], [ -95.30586, 29.8602 ], [ -95.30586, 29.86079 ], [ -95.30495, 29.86079 ], [ -95.30407, 29.86079 ], [ -95.30323, 29.8608 ], [ -95.30321, 29.8608 ], [ -95.30235, 29.8608 ], [ -95.3015, 29.8608 ], [ -95.30053, 29.86077 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30049, 29.85327 ], [ -95.30051, 29.85453 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.3005, 29.85283 ], [ -95.30049, 29.85307 ], [ -95.30049, 29.85327 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30575, 29.8563 ], [ -95.30531, 29.85645 ], [ -95.30504, 29.85656 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "speed": "45" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -95.30504, 29.85656 ], [ -95.30356, 29.85715 ] ] } }
]
}
```

I am trying to identify the feature nearest to a given point. For example, the feature nearest to the point (-95.29756, 29.85736) for the given GeoJSON. Is there any efficient way to do this using any python libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) is a library that is very useful to do spatial analysis in python. It has a function to compute the nearest points between two shapes: [`shapely.ops.nearest_points()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.nearest_points)

Here is a code snippet showing how you would go about using it in your case:

```py
import json

from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping, shape
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

with open("g.geojson") as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

ref_point = Point(-95.29756, 29.85736)

features = []
min_distance = None
min_index = None

for i, feature in enumerate(geojson["features"]):

    # Could be improved with Haversine distance, or distance in UTM coordinates for example
    p1, p2 = nearest_points(shape(feature["geometry"]), ref_point)
    distance = p1.distance(p2)

    if min_distance is None or distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        min_index = i

    feature["properties"] = {"index": i, "distance": distance}
    features.append(feature)
    features.append(
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {"index": f"closest_point_{i}", "distance": distance},
            "geometry": mapping(p1),
        }
    )

features = sorted(features, key=lambda x: x["properties"]["distance"])

features.append(
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"index": "ref_point", "distance": 0},
        "geometry": mapping(ref_point),
    }
)

with open("gg.geojson", "w") as f:
    json.dump({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}, f)
```

You can then open `gg.geojson` in geojson.io for example:

[image]

Here I've kept it simple and used an Euclidean distance between the points, but this is approximate since longitude/latitude coordinates are spherical.
On your example, it doesn't matter much because distances are very small, but if you wanted to be generic, you could use the [Haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), or you could convert your coordinates to UTM using [pyproj](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj) before calling `nearest_points()`.